# Docker app in Exited (0) status

Tags: node.js, docker, exit, dockerfile

I'm trying to run a little server application in a Docker container

index.js

```
var server_port = 3111
, http     = require('http')
, mosca    = require('mosca')
, dispatch = require('dispatch')
, httpServ = http.createServer(
    dispatch({
        '/': function(req, res, next){
            console.log('in route');
        }
    })
);

httpServ.listen(server_port, function() {
    console.log("listening on", server_port);
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "dispatch": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "description": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.4"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "name": "SimpleServer",
  "version": "0.0.1"
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM    centos:centos6

# Enable EPEL for Node.js
RUN     rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
# Install Node.js and npm
RUN     yum install -y npm

# Install nodemon
RUN npm install -g nodemon

# Bundle app source
COPY . /src
# Install app dependencies
RUN cd /src; npm install

# Expose port
EXPOSE  3111

# Run app using nodemon
RUN echo "***" && pwd && echo "***"
CMD ["nodemon", "/src/index.js"]
```

In the Docker Terminal, and within the SimpleServer working directory, the command `$ docker build -t test_simple  .` resulted in `Successfully built 43c8806574f4`. Any attempt so far to run the image in a container, such as `$ docker run -p 3111 test_simple` consistently results in the code exiting, and the server not running.

```
$ docker run -p 3111 test_simple
19 Aug 07:22:56 - [nodemon] v1.4.1
19 Aug 07:22:56 - [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
19 Aug 07:22:56 - [nodemon] watching: *.*
19 Aug 07:22:56 - [nodemon] starting `node /src/index.js`
Master: 16
19 Aug 07:22:57 - [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart

$ docker run -d -P test_simple node /src/index.js
a0a56ec5c13161bc37b523be0e32edec0a43ca82e7db88ddb2a91688f745b24b

$ docker ps -l
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
a0a56ec5c131        test_simple         "node /src/index.js"   6 seconds ago       Exited (0) 6 seconds ago                       jolly_bohr
```

I cannot tell what's going on, and why the server is exiting. Any feedback is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `docker run --rm -it test_simple bash` to get a shell into the container, then try to run `nodemon /src/index.js` manually and find out what may go wrong there, as well as run `node` directly instead of `nodemon` while debugging this issue.

Also, it may be better to base off [the official node image](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/)

Comment: I'm getting some weird behavior: `$ docker exec -it test_simple bash
Error response from daemon: no such id: test_simple`. `$ docker images
REPOSITORY                             TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
test_simple                            latest              f080110b21c8        45 seconds ago      557.2 MB`. `$ docker exec -it f080110b21c8 bash
Error response from daemon: no such id: f080110b21c8`.

Comment: what does your `docker images` return? you did build the image with the tag `test_simple` did you?

Comment: ah, the comment garbled that up - your images shows `test_simple:latest` try `docker run -it --rm test_simple:latest bash` (also note that I edited my answer to use **run** instead of **exec**) - I had that wrong initially.

Comment: `docker run --rm -it test_simple bash` is good. It shows the code exiting with the `[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart`.

Comment: try running node directly

Comment: The directory looks good. This gives me something to work with. `[root@6186a13be58b src]# node index.js 
Master: 48
[root@6186a13be58b src]# node
> console.log('hello')
hello
undefined`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87348/discussion-between-vincent-de-smet-and-aug2uag).

Comment: Ok, I have an additional library in my SimpleServer that's not in the package.json --

Comment: It seems Docker doesn't like cluster. I had to get rid of it for the code to work. Thanks for your help, this solved it for me for today.